# How to select all values from the Dropdown or select only individual values using SQL query in VBA?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to pull the sql table to my excel worksheet based on the dates and location entered by the user.

Cell E6 has a data validation dropdown list of locations such as blank space, followed by Boston, Chicago, Houston, New York and LA. The list is defined from values in `H8:H19`.

The following code actually works fine for the `Else` part, where the results are filter based on the location selected by the user other than blank space.

But when the cell `E6` is empty i.e. when no location is selected it should output the data for all the locations. Any suggestions or opinions on this regard would be much appreciated.

```
If IsEmpty(Range("E6")) Then Reg = Range("H8:H19").Value Else Reg = Range("E6").Value
```

My SQL query code that pulls the data to Excel is as follows:

```
     objMyCmd.CommandText = " SELECT a.[RDT_FileID],a.[Master Policy Number], a.[Work item /Submission no#],a.[Insured Name], a.[Credited Office]," & _
                                " a.[Credited Underwriter], a.[Product Line], a.[Product Line Subtype], a.[Current Status], a.[Effective Date], a.[Expiry Date],  a.[Premium in USD $] " & _
                                " FROM  DB1.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record a " & _
                                " WHERE a.[Master Policy Number] Is Not Null " & _
                                " AND a.[RDT_FileID] is null " & _
                                " AND a.[Product Line Subtype] <>  '0102-Marine' " & _
                                " AND a.[Effective Date] >= " & PED(0) & " and a.[Effective Date] <= " & PED(1) & " " & _
                                " AND a.[Current Status] ='Bound' " & _
                                " AND a.[Credited Office] = '" & Reg & "'"
```

[image]

Comment: shouldn't your sql statement be like `" AND a.[Credited Office] = * "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send all items into the SQL then instead of e.g.:

```
AND a.[Credited Office] = '001 - Boston'
```

You need:

```
AND a.[Credited Office] IN ('001 - Boston', '002 - New York') 'etc
```

So if your input `E6` is empty the sample code is like below. Note the use of the `Transpose` function to convert a `Range` to an `Array` so you can use the `Join` function.

```
If IsEmpty(Range("e6")) Then
    Reg = " IN ('" & Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("H8:H19").Value), "','") & "')"
End If
```

You will have to adapt your code a little setting the `CommandText` to deal with the new `AND` clause. Note that if your list in `H8:H19` is, in fact, every option that occurs in your `Credited Office` field then you can just drop the `AND` statement altogether as you don't require a filter.